# python requests.post is interpreted as GET

Tags: python, post

I am interfacing with an external API using python's request module. When I submit the request using **requests.post()** the API returns with

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}
```

When I try the **exact same request with my browser's RESTED client** (also using POST method), it **works just fine**.

Not really much in the way of sample code to give, it's just a simple

```
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

It would seem the fault is either on the API's side and/or python for not submitting an entirely standard POST request (since it works with RESTED). Has anyone ever run into this scenario before? Is there a python alternative to requests.post()?
I'm on Python 3.9.1 on Windows.

Comment: Make sure you are running the code you think you are running. Delete all `*.pyc` files and run your code again

Comment: Valid thought. Moved to a new directory, added print statements to make sure it was running the current code, still the same problem.